# Pandas extract in another column the reference name, middle name and surname

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

using jupyter with pandas I would need to extract in another column the reference that happens after any colon, for example:

```
nameis: joe doe, the student is....
nameis: patric test, this question is...
nameis: franck joe and he is.....
nameis: lucash de brown and the academic achievement......
```

the question becomes complex for me precisely when I have to extract just after nameis: the name and surname, unfortunately subsequently articulated by any text! the only reference in this case is nameis: which is recurring and I would like to put the name and surname on another dedicated column!

```
first_last_name,column_2....
joe doe,....
patric test,....
franck joe,......
lucash de brown,.....
```

not all names and surnames end with a comma, but in the extreme I am happy to bring only those!
In the meantime, I thought of bringing the name closer to nameis:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.replace(r'nameis: ', '')
```

and then something like that, but unfortunately I'm still! especially when dealing with middle names

```
pat=r'([nameis:]+[a-zA-Z])'
df['first_last_name']=df['column'].str.extract(pat,expand=False)
df
```

thanks to anyone who helps me!

> UPDATE:

perfect operation of the string capture:

```
df['column'].str.extract('nameis: (?P<first_last_name>[^,]+?)(?:,|\s*and) (?P<column_2>.*)')
```

I need further clarification on this matter:
if in the same line I have more **nameis:** how can I also extract the seconds..thirds..etc?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
nameis: joe doe, the student is has excellent marks in the subject of professor nameis: adrian muller, ....
nameis: patric test, in the subject of the teacher nameis: adam joe, ...
```

with:

```
df['column'].str.extract('nameis: (?P<first_last_name>[^,]+?)(?:,|\s*and) (?P<column_2>.*)')
```

I can only extract the first **nameis:**! how can i do to extract them both and put them on the same column separated by a comma ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and a regex with named capturing groups:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['nameis: joe doe, the student is....',
                              'nameis: patric test, this question is...',
                              'nameis: franck joe and he is.....',
                              'nameis: lucash de brown and the academic achievement......']})

df['column'].str.extract('nameis: (?P<first_last_name>[^,]+?)(?:,|\s*and) (?P<column_2>.*)')
```

output:

```
   first_last_name                        column_2
0          joe doe              the student is....
1      patric test             this question is...
2       franck joe                      he is.....
3  lucash de brown  the academic achievement......
```

If you just want the name:

```
print(df['column'].str.extract('nameis: (?P<first_last_name>[^,]+?)(?:,|\s*and)'))
```

output:

```
   first_last_name
0          joe doe
1      patric test
2       franck joe 
3  lucash de brown
```

Comment: that's fine thanks .... unfortunately I have to have a reference :) on a sentence like: jon bwown born in london ... etc etc ... it's a mess

Comment: some parts of the text do not end with and or comma .... however it is perfect, but i think it's impossible without a reference! thanks again!

Comment: I have updated the question with another question! could you help me :)

Comment: @scofx the good practice is to open a new question for clarity (you can reference this one). You should be able to use `extractall` but again you should provide the exact output that you expect ;)

Comment: ah sorry I thought that opening a new question on the same was wrong! I tried with extractall but nothing ... if anything, I try to open a new discussion! Thank you!

Comment: Well it depends, if this is really a minor thing or not, please provide the expected output, this might be simple (or not)

Comment: df["full_name"] = df['combined'].str.extractall('"nameis":(?P<full_name>[^,]+?)(?:,|\s*") (?P<column_2>.*)')
df
out:

TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index ....with str.extract work fine!